# Android WorkManager: Meaning of the NotNull-annotation

Tags: java, android

What meaning has the NotNull-annotation in this case?

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    return Result.success();
}
```

Does it mean that I get a warning if I try to return null? The annotation doesn't prevent me from return null? It only gives me a runtime-warning or what's the result of having it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the annotation is to let the developers know that this functions expects a non null `Result` and may throw `NullPointerException` if null is returned.

For more [see](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html)